# How do you specify which program you want to stop in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I got two programs that are pretty simple programs.

Here is 1:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    PipeClient client = new PipeClient();
    client.Send("Hello World");
    client.Send("Hello World 2");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

here is 2

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var server = new PipeServer())
    {
        server.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to End");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I go to the solution properties and under common Properties I set the Configuration like this:
[image]

I start the debugger.

Both programs start, now I want to use the break all functionality because I want to inspect one of the two programs; however, when I use the break all icon, I can only inspect one of the two projects. How do I allow myself to view both if that is possible and if not how do I toggle which program I'm inspecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj919165.aspx) says "On the Debug Location toolbar, choose Process to view the Process list box. Select the process that you want to designate as current process.
Switch between processes"

[image]